# Como separar string no jquery do autocomplete?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, pdo, jquery-ui

Estou tendo problemas pra fazer um sistema de search, no momento eu faço a busca/comparação com 2 colunas e mostra o nome das 2 colunas.

```
  $pesquisa = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'term', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

  $result_pesquisa = "SELECT Ativo, Empresa FROM tb_ativos WHERE Ativo LIKE '%{$pesquisa}%' OR Empresa LIKE '%{$pesquisa}%' ORDER BY Ativo ASC LIMIT 10";

  $resultado_final = $conn->prepare($result_pesquisa);
  $resultado_final->execute();

  while($row_pesquisa = $resultado_final->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $data[] = $row_pesquisa['Ativo'] . " - " . $row_pesquisa['Empresa'];

  }

  echo json_encode($data);
```

Na página principal tem esse trecho

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
        $("#ativo").autocomplete({
          source: 'pesquisa-ativo.php'
        });
      });
    </script>
```

E me retorna oq eu quero, n importa se o usuário escreva o nome correspondente da primeira ou segunda coluna, irá aparecer a msm coisa para os dois

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na página principal tem um código parecido com o primeiro mencionado, mas mostrando o id tbm como resultado, se eu tento escrever qualquer nome q esteja nas 2 colunas e dar Enter ele irá me retornar a msm coisa, até aí tudo bem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema está quando eu clico em uma das sugestões de busca e realizo a pesquisa, como n existe em nenhuma coluna a junção dos dois nomes, ele n retorna a pesquisa

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de saber como pegar apenas a primeira palavra quando selecionado uma das opções sugeridas do autocomplete, acredito que consiga tratar com o jquery nesse trecho do código, mas n estou conseguindo fazer

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
        $("#ativo").autocomplete({
          source: 'pesquisa-ativo.php'
        });
      });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom dia Lxxx_190,

Pelo o que eu intendi você tem uma string que é montada com 2 informações para ser exibida no autocomplete, mas na hora de escolher uma das opções você precisa buscar a informação no banco com as 2 informações separadas.
Pra isso você pode resolver de 2 formas:

1. Separar os valores com javascript "Lado Cliente", aqui você quebra a string em um array com os valores separados sempre quebrando a string onde for encontrado o padrão determinado. Aqui no caso eu determinei o padrão ' - '

   ```
      const infos = string.split(' - ')
   ```
2. Separar a string usando o php "lado servidor", nessa opção você não simplesmente envia pro seu php a string completa e separa usando o método "explode" que é similar ao split do javascript, também gera um array de string quebrando onde encontra os padrões.

   ```
      $infos = explode(' - ', string)
   ```

depois de separadas as infos você pode fazer a query no banco de dados buscando exatamente o que você quer.

Espero ter ajudado!